# Different output after execution main class

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(X.Y.Z);
    }
}

class X {
    static class Y {
        static String Z = "Result 1";
    }
    static C Y = new C();
}

class C {
    String Z = "Result 2";
}
```

Sometime output is `"Result 1"` and sometime output is `"Result 2"`. Can you explain why?

I am using `JDK 1.6_33`.

Comment: With JDK 1.6.24, I get `Result 2` every single time.

Comment: @mellamokb Me too. Every time.

Comment: I downloaded JDK 1.6.33, and compiled and ran the code snippet 20 times.  Got `Result 2` every single time.

Comment: It's strange this result, as even if your jdk is buggy, once compiled, the code should produce just one type of result: the compiler either puts in a field access or an inner class access and that should be it.

Comment: Now I can't reproduce Result 1... May be it's my mistake. Oh, my poor eyesight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Java Puzzler #68 - it should always print `Result 2`. Quote:

> It turns out that there is a rule that governs program behavior under these circumstances. When a
>   variable and a type have the same name and both are in scope, the variable name takes
>   precedence [JLS 6.5.2]. The variable name is said to obscure the type name [JLS 6.3.2]. Similarly,
>   variable and type names can obscure package names. This rule is indeed obscure, and any
>   program that depends on it is likely to confuse its readers.

Comment: And anyone writing code that relies on this should be rolled into tar and feather.

Comment: Where can I see this Java puzzles?

Comment: Nice puzzle. I managed to get "Result 1" by `X.Y ref=null; System.out.println(ref.Z);`. You think it is good practice or is there better way?

Comment: @Pshemo I am not sure what you call "good practice" - the original code is not good practice to start with. Good practice = avoid anything ambiguous.